# Nicer class names in PostCSS

Tags: webpack-2, postcss

I'm building my app using `Webpack 2`. I'm using `PostCSS 2` for CSS modules. Here is my CSS importing configuration for Webpack:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
          importLoaders: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          plugins: loader => [
            require("postcss-import")({
              path: './js',
              addDependencyTo: webpack,
            }),
            require('postcss-cssnext')(),
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

Now, the problem is, that this generates really ugly class names. Example using React:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styles from './Element.css';

export default class Element extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <div className={styles.myElement}>This is an example.</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Renders into:

```
<div class="_1DHVkmCxFFQMFYac-L_MIg">This is an example.</div>
```

Now, this is fine in production, but in development, something like `class="myElement--_1DHVkmCxFFQMFYac-L_MIg"` would be a lot nicer. I found a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/90) discussing this, but as I'm new to Webpack, I couldn't figure out how to implement their suggestion. Whatever I tried resulted in an error, where Webpack couldn't resolve the module.

I tried adding `localIdentName: '[local]--[hash:base64:5]'` to `postcss-loader` options, but that did nothing.

So, how do I retain the original class name in the generated class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this line to the `css-loader` resolved it:

```
localIdentName: debug ? '[name]_[local]___[hash:base64:10]' : undefined,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      modules: true,
      importLoaders: 1,
      minimize: false, //this line!!
    },
  },
```

you can use minimize: !isDebug and isDebug is a bool to know if you are debugging or not. but setting to false should leave "nice names"

Comment: This didn't affect the class names that PostCSS generates. None of my code was being minifed, anyway.